# StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle SoftDeleteable

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I use https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/SoftDeleteableListener.php.

What is purpose to use propertyChanged() method in SoftDeleteable Listener?

Everything works perfectly without this action.
From what Doctrine says, propertyChanged() notifies this UnitOfWork of a property change in an entity.
Notifies and what's next?

```
class SoftDeleteableListener extends MappedEventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * Pre soft-delete event
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const PRE_SOFT_DELETE = "preSoftDelete";

    /**
     * Post soft-delete event
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const POST_SOFT_DELETE = "postSoftDelete";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'loadClassMetadata',
            'onFlush',
        );
    }

    /**
     * If it's a SoftDeleteable object, update the "deletedAt" field
     * and skip the removal of the object
     *
     * @param EventArgs $args
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
    {
        $ea = $this->getEventAdapter($args);
        $om = $ea->getObjectManager();
        $uow = $om->getUnitOfWork();
        $evm = $om->getEventManager();

        //getScheduledDocumentDeletions
        foreach ($ea->getScheduledObjectDeletions($uow) as $object) {
            $meta = $om->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
            $config = $this->getConfiguration($om, $meta->name);

            if (isset($config['softDeleteable']) && $config['softDeleteable']) {
                $reflProp = $meta->getReflectionProperty($config['fieldName']);
                $oldValue = $reflProp->getValue($object);
                $date = new \DateTime();

                // Remove `$oldValue instanceof \DateTime` check when PHP version is bumped to >=5.5
                if (isset($config['hardDelete']) && $config['hardDelete'] && ($oldValue instanceof \DateTime || $oldValue instanceof \DateTimeInterface) && $oldValue <= $date) {
                    continue; // want to hard delete
                }

                $evm->dispatchEvent(
                    self::PRE_SOFT_DELETE,
                    $ea->createLifecycleEventArgsInstance($object, $om)
                );


                $reflProp->setValue($object, $date);

                $om->persist($object);
                $uow->propertyChanged($object, $config['fieldName'], $oldValue, $date);
                if ($uow instanceof MongoDBUnitOfWork && !method_exists($uow, 'scheduleExtraUpdate')) {
                    $ea->recomputeSingleObjectChangeSet($uow, $meta, $object);
                } else {
                    $uow->scheduleExtraUpdate($object, array(
                        $config['fieldName'] => array($oldValue, $date),
                    ));
                }

                $evm->dispatchEvent(
                    self::POST_SOFT_DELETE,
                    $ea->createLifecycleEventArgsInstance($object, $om)
                );
            }
        }
    }
```